# python eve - data_relation on DELETE - preserve/error if referenced

Tags: python, eve

currently when I DELETE an item which is being referenced by. I can still delete it. I would like to prohibit this giving an error. I couldn't find anything on http://docs.python-eve.org or google.

say I have the following two schemas:

```
foos = {
  ...
  'schema' : {
    ...,
    'bar': {
      'type': 'string',
      'required': true,
      'data_relation': {
        'resource': 'bars',
        'field': 'name',
        'embeddable': True
      }
    }
  }
}

bars = {
  ...
  'schema' : {
    ...,
    'name': {
      'type': 'string',
      'required': true,
    }
  }
}
```

if I delete now an item from bars which is still being referenced by >=1 items in foos. How could I return an error instead of deleting the bars item?

Would i need to write a

```
on_delete_item
def event(resource_name, item)
```

and how? Any help is appreciated.